# Азы арифметических выражеий Python3

Tags: python

В тупике второй вечер из-за этого:

**Задача**На которую необходимо дать ответ.
Дополните программу, которая вычисляет значение переменной `y` по формуле:

`y = (1-x**2+2,5x**3+x**4)**2`

Значение переменной `x` целое и задается с клавиатуры.
Вывести вычисленное значение переменной `y` на экран

```py
x = 
y = 
print(y) # редактировать эту строку нельзя
```

Задание брал с silvertests.ru, практика по арифметическим выражениям.Не школьник, просто учусь)

Comment: О каком тупике речь? В чём проблема у вас?

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает что вам надо вместо `2,5` написать `2.5`

Comment: По тексту задачи гуглится вот это https://silvertests.ru/CourseTask.aspx?id=33497&idcourse=32159

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка при переводе в код может возникнуть из-за того, что десятичные дроби указываются через точку.
То есть:
2.5 - корректная запись числа «два с половиной».
2,5 - это два разных числа (кортеж, если угодно)

Также обратите внимание на то, что конструкция вида 2x некорректна с точки зрения кода. Необходимо четко прописывать знаки арифметических операций 2 * x.
Полное решение задачи в вашем случае будет выглядеть так:

```
x = int(input())
y = (1-x**2+(2.5*x)**3+x**4)**2
print(y)
```

Comment: зачем вы помогаете тем, кто даже не потрудился открыть учебник?

Comment: Чуть небольшая корректировка

Comment: y =(1-x**2+(2.5*(x**3))+x**4)**2

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что программа должна принять следующий вид:

```
x = float(input())
y = ((1-x)**2+(2.5*x)**3+x**4)**2
print(y)
```

`x = float(input())` - конструкция получения данных из консольного ввода, который преобразовывается в число с плавающей точкой, так же при необходимости значение можно задать сразу, к примеру `x = 5.6`

в данном случае конструкция `(1-x**2+2,5x**3+x**4)**2`  может читаться как:
`((1-x)^2 + (2.5*x)^3 + x^4)^2`, где символ ^ равен **, что равно возведению в степень. Запятая в конструкции 2,5x была заменена на точку т.к. это синтаксис записи числа с плавающей точкой принятый в Python.

Comment: зачем вы помогаете тем, кто даже не потрудился открыть учебник?

Comment: @Эникейщик, всем репы поднять хочется, а такие элементарные вопросы идут нарасхват)

Comment: @Эникейщик, собственно это является проблемой или чем-то ненормальным? С ваших слов создается впечатление словно это что-то неправильное.

Comment: Да, это неправильно. По сути вы просто сделали домашку какому-то лентяю. Тем самым вы поощряете низкокачественные вопросы. Вопрошающий не приложил ни малейших усилий, чтобы решить свою проблему, его вопрос не удовлетворяет минимальным требованиям к вопросу. И вам еще повезло, то ваш ответ никто не минусовал, нередко такие ответы получают несколько минусов.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0

Comment: @Эникейщик, понятно, ну причина осуждения ясна, на текущий момент все еще не появилось способа закрывать похожие вопросы? Только если минусовать?

Comment: способ всегда был - 5 голосов за закрытие. Сейчас их 4.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию

Comment: @Эникейщик Интересно было узнать вашу реакцию на ваш же ответ ,когда вы только начинали разбираться в python. Оба данных ответа неверные. Я уверен вы не ответили правильно тоже. А тем кто не страдает ЧСВ спасибо и лайк!

Comment: @Sam попробуй выразить свою мысль более понятно. Мою реакцию на какой мой ответ? Я вообще-то тут не отвечал. И поэтому мой ответ не может быть правильным или неправильным. И если оба данных ответа неверные, то зачем же ты отметил один из них как верный?

Comment: И когда я начинал разбираться в питоне, я РАЗБИРАЛСЯ в питоне, а не просил других сделать за меня элементарнейшие вещи. Хотя дело твое, не будешь сам разбираться - никогда не начнешь разбираться.

Comment: Вся суть заключается в том чтобы правильно дать ответ . И если ни кто не даёт правильный ответ то вопрос не такой уж простой.

Comment: @Эникейщик У тебя существует регламент на принятия ответов на твои вопросы?

Comment: "_Вся суть заключается в том чтобы правильно дать ответ_" - тут ты очень сильно ошибаешься. "_если ни кто не даёт правильный ответ то вопрос не такой уж простой._" - Или же вопрос настолько элементарный, что всем ясно, что вопрошающий даже две страницы учебника не прочитал (как в твоем случае). Ты, кстати, даже не осилил задать вопрос. Только сообщил всему миру, что не можешь записать элементарную формулу.

Comment: Что значит элементарный? Даже тот кто дал более правильный ответ ошибся в порядке математических действий. Я с тобой в принципе согласен, но иногда можно помогать тем кто не совсем понимает даже как кажется некоторым в элементарных вопросах